# Best way to integrate QBD Canadian version

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

We are working on an application that take estimates(description and number of hours or quantity) from the contractors and save it in a database online. Now, we want to take that estimate and sync it with QuickBooks desktop Canadian Version so that the head office users can create the Quotes/Estimates using the information entered in by the contractors. I have looked at a couple of solution that I think should work but the CANADIAN Version of QBD doesn't support that feature(I think) so I'm actively looking for a solution. The features that I looked are as follows:

- QBWC - Quickbooks Web Connector (According to [this link](http://marketplace.intuit.com/webconnector/) below it supports Canadian version of QB 2003-2013)
- Intuit Anywhere

Now, my question is there any way to fetch or add data to QBD Canadian Version? Looking forward for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Web Connector will work fine.

Intuit Anywhere *only supports US versions of QuickBooks right now*. At some point in the future, it will likely support non-US versions (the beta v3 API is designed to be internationalized), but they are not supported yet.

Comment: Intuit Anywhere supports only SaaS applications

FAQ -https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq#What_types_of_applications_are_supported_with_QuickBooks_API.3F

Some additional ref docs related to web connector

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb/0010_get_oriented

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb/0010_get_oriented/0080_quickbooks_web_connector

Answer (score 0):

The QuickBooks API (Intuit Anywhere) will only be supported for global versions of QuickBooks Online. It will not be supported for desktop versions of QuickBooks Canada.

You can use the QuickBooks SDK or depening on what you are looking to do, you can use our platform, Method Integration. We've already created a sync engine that syncs data in real-time using the SDK and support all international versions of QuickBooks.

www.methodhq.com

Comment: Where are you getting this information? Intuit has specifically said multiple times that international, desktop versions of QuickBooks will be supported...

Comment: @KeithPalmer-consolibyte I've been in touch with the PM of Quickbooks Global, and told quite clearly that they don't intend to implement support for QBD in other regions. I know... it sucks. You can still try and swing it by voting up their user voice at http://intuitpartnerplatform.uservoice.com/forums/182764-ipp

Comment: @Forrest Thanks for the info... very interesting. Definitely sucks.